# MVC4 Assigning Value to Bootstrap Tag Text Box using bootstrap-tagsinput

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, bootstrap-tags-input

Using the bootstrap-tagsinputs plugin I want to assign values to the textbox when the view gets loaded.

The value format been passed to the view is "a,b,c"

This works

`@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.mylist, new {@class = "form-control"})`

but when I add data_role = "tagsinput" it doesn't work

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.mylist, new {@class = "form-control", data_role = "tagsinput" })
```

also tried to do but no luck

```
$(function () {

    var elt = $("#mylisttags-input");
    elt.tagsinput({
        itemText: "@Model.mylist"
        });
 });
```

How do I configure so it shows in the textbox?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

try it,

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.mylist, new {@class = "form-control", data_role = "tagsinput" })

 $("#mylisttags-input").tagsinput('items'); // to show just pass the items key
```

http://jsfiddle.net/754wob2q/

Comment: In your example you provided you set the values by default. I am trying to pass values from the controller to the view in a model parameter and assign it to the textbox.